# vim buffer write destination set to stdin

Tags: vim

*EDIT*: it turns out if I write to a temporary `.go` file in the same directory I can then start writing the file again, so I'm almost certain this is a vim-syntastic issue. Going to mark this as closed.

I have an infrequent (but extremely annoying) bug where vim gets confused about where a file is supposed to be written to. It will suddenly decide that it should be writing to "-stdin-", even though `:echo expand('%:p')` is showing the correct file.

When this happens, there's basically no way to write the buffer back to the correct file. `:w %` doesn't help, nor does `:w NameOfFile.go`. I can write to a different filename just fine. `:bd` does not fix the issue. This only happens if there's a location list open.

Given the lack of google hits for this, I'm guessing this is some kind of issue with my local config. How can I go about debugging this problem?

*Edit to add:* after posting this, I realized that this is very possibly related to vim-syntastic. I've [opened an issue there](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/2092), but it's definitely possible there's something else causing this.

Comment: Are you saying when you type `:w` it doesn't actually write the file?

Comment: Correct. Instead it gives me `"-stdin" E212: Can't open file for writing`.

Comment: `E212: For some reason the file you are writing to cannot be created or overwritten. The reason could be that you do not have permission to write in the directory or the file name is not valid.`


The directory you are accessing could also not exist. Try to open with sudo or make sure the directory exists if you are creating a file in a directory you aren't already in.

Comment: The file already exists according to `:echo expand('%:p)` (which is a fully qualified path). And if that was the case it shouldn't be spitting out "-stdin-".

Comment: Are you using neovim by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Marking as closed since this appears to be a vim-syntastic issue.

Comment: FYI could be also realted to this issue in neovim
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6814